# Change Logo URL based on Store

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a small request.. Is there code that I can use to change the logo link on the website to lead to /en/ on the English side and / on the Indonesian side?

This is the code right now

```
<h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt(); ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl(''); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt(); ?>" class="logo"><img width="170" height="65" src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt(); ?>" /></a></h1>
```

The Indonesian side is linking to /id/ which isn't the homepage for that store. All of the folders have /id/ but the actual homepage is just the root /

Happy holidays :) Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using different url that you have setup in admin for engligh and indonesian, then replace

```
echo $this->getUrl('');
```

with

```
echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK)
```

in the example that you have given.

Comment: Like I said it's already linking to the base URL. It's already linking to /id/ and /en/

What I NEED to happen is for it to link to / on the Indonesian (/id/) side and not /id/ but ONLY for the homepage logo link

Comment: Anybody........?